# Problema con errores en forms Django

Tags: python, django

Estoy teniendo un problema con mi forms. Hice una funcion que verifique si las contraseñas son iguales, si esto no es asi devuelve un raise con un mensaje. El problema que ese mensaje no me sale. Tengo otras 2 funciones muy parecidas con el username y el email y si funcionan.

Cambios: Adjunte todo el codigo del forms y tambien el del html.
Probe cambiando la funcion de clean sacando el data, y obteniendo los datos a traves del self.cleaned_data, pero sigue igual. En la otra aplicacion que habia hecho en modo de practica no hubo ningun problema.

Dejo el codigo:

forms.py

```
class SignupForm(forms.Form):
username = forms.CharField(
    min_length=4,
    max_length=50,
    label='Nombre de usuario'
)
password = forms.CharField(
    min_length=4,
    max_length=50,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    label="Contraseña"
)
password_confirmation = forms.CharField(
    min_length=4,
    max_length=50,
    widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    label='Confirmar contraseña'
)

first_name = forms.CharField(
    min_length=2,
    max_length=50,
    label='Nombre'
)
last_name = forms.CharField(
    min_length=2,
    max_length=50,
    label='Apellido'
)
email = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.EmailInput(),
    label='Email'
)
def clean_username(self):
    username = self.cleaned_data['username']
    username_taken = User.objects.filter(username=username).exists()
    if username_taken:
        raise forms.ValidationError('El nombre de usuario ya esta en uso.')
    return username
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    email_taken = User.objects.filter(email=email).exists()
    if email_taken:
        raise forms.ValidationError('El email ya esta en uso.')
    return email
def clean(self):
    data = super().clean()
    password = data['password']
    password_confirmation = data['password_confirmation']
    if password != password_confirmation:
        raise forms.ValidationError('Las contraseñas no coinciden.')
    return data
def save(self):
    data = self.cleaned_data
    data.pop('password_confirmation')
    user = User.objects.create_user(**data)
    profile = Profile(user=user)
    profile.save()
```

signup.html

```
<form action="{% url 'users:signup' %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% for field in form %}
                <p>
                    {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
                    {{ field }}
                {% for error in field.errors %}
                    {{ error }}
                {% endfor %}
                </p>
            {% endfor %}
            <br>
            <button class="register-button" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
        </form>
```

Comment: Lo acabo de probar, y funciona, estas seguro que muestras los errores en el template?. Por otra parte adjunta todo el form y el template.

Comment: Subi las partes del codigo @JulioCesar

Comment: Acabo de publicar mi respuesta, échale un vistaso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que el error que levantas **no es de un campo en especifico** y esto es porque lo levantas en el método `clean`, y tu **solo muestras los errores de los campos**:

```
{% for error in field.errors %}
    {{ error }}
{% endfor %}
```

Entonces hay varias soluciones, una es indicando el campo al momento de levantar la excepción `ValidationError`:

```
raise forms.ValidationError({
    'password_confirmation': forms.ValidationError('Las contraseñas no coinciden.')
})
```

O puedes hacerlo así (personalmente, yo uso esta forma, es mejor, ademas que solo tienes que llamar el método y ya):

> ```
> self.add_error('password_confirmation', forms.ValidationError('Las contraseñas no coinciden.'))
> ```
>
> O así:
>
> ```
> self.add_error('password_confirmation', 'Las contraseñas no coinciden.')
> ```
>
> Django recomienda la primera forma, pero en la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), usa la segunda
> forma, y pues....
>
> El caso es si usas la segunda forma, Django se encarga de convertir el
> mensaje de error (`str`) a una instancia de `ValidationError`, esto se
> puede ver en el código fuente (*method
> [`add_error`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py#L308)*):
>
> ```
> def add_error(self, field, error):
>     """
>     ...
>     """
>     if not isinstance(error, ValidationError):
>         # Normalize to ValidationError and let its constructor
>         # do the hard work of making sense of the input.
>         error = ValidationError(error)
> ```
>
> Entonces no se cual de las dos es mejor XD....
>
> Por otra parte cabe recalcar que si utilizamos el método `add_error`,
> se elimina automáticamente el campo del `cleaned_data`.

---

Si no quieres hacer lo anterior, entonces tu `<form>` puede ser así:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{ form.errors }} <---

    {% for field in form %}
        <p>
            {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
            {{ field }}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <br>
    <button class="register-button" type="submit">Registrarse</button>
</form>
```

El "problema" es que el error se mostrara al principio del form (o puedes ponerlo abajo).

Espero haberte ayudado.